# How to fix this issue in my code (Node.js&Discord.js): "node:8036"?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm started programming yesterday and i wanted to make a bot. I have a small issue and I can't fix him. Error = "(node:8188) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: bread is not defined". Line of code = "return message.channel.send({files: [bread.png]});". Thank you in advance.

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let prefix = '!';
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if(cmd === `${prefix}bulka`) {
        return message.channel.send({files: [bread.png]});
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in this line:

```
return message.channel.send({files: [bread.png]});
```

Use:

```
return message.channel.send({files: ["bread.png"]});
```

If you want to use a string inside an array, you need to wrap the text in single quotes (`'`), double quotes (`"`), or grave accents (`` ` ``) to let JS know that it's a literal string. If you use `bread.png`, Node.js looks for the global object or variable `bread` and its property `png`.